# How to forward exception from Servlet to JSP

Tags: jsp, exception, servlets

I have a form.html in which I defined a servlet as action parameter.
The servlet inturn talk with model(simple java class DAO to access database) and if record not found it throws recordnotfound exception which is inturn delegated to servlet from class.
So,I want to forward this exception(RecordNotFound) to jsp page defined in web.xml

Any ideas how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, from an end user point of view? Dislay an error message in the page? Display the stack trace of the exception in the page?

Comment: i am doing this for learning purpose so I would say both

Comment: An exception is an object like every other object. So you can catch it in the servlet, store it in a request attribute, forward to a JSP, and have the JSP get it from the request attribute and doing whatever it wants with it.

Comment: Request/session attribute is what came to my  mind but How can I invoke the error page which is defined in web.xml via this

Comment: Just let the exception propagate, and the error page will be executed by the container.

Comment: so,you are saying that after setting the exception in request/session scope and forarding it to say handle.jsp,exception will propagate to error page automatically?

Comment: No. I'm saying that if the servlet doesn't catch the exception, and simply lets it propagate, the container will cacth it, and invoke the appropriate error page.

Answer (score 0):

Therefor the `<error-page>` entry in `web.xml` can be used.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.exampl.RecordNotFound</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/recordnotfound.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

All you need to do in your servlet is to just let the thrown exception go, or if it's a checked one, to wrap it in a `ServletException`.

```
} catch (RecordNotFound e) {
    throw new ServletException(e);
}
```

Note that you shouldn't have an overly generic error page on `java.lang.Throwable` or some superclass of `ServletException`, otherwise that one would be used instesd. The container will namely make 2 passes through the error page locations. First one using the exact exception and second one if the exception is actually a `ServletException`, the wrapped exception will then be used instead to locate the error page.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/yourJSPFile.jsp").forward(request,response);
```